# Dynamically adding select2 dropdown are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have a small requirement, where i need to make a form repeater that contains one of the fields as a select dropdown. I have create a jsfiddle to reproduce the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/varun9522/gwb3rLp9/9/

[Js Fiddle link with sample code and issue reproduced][1]

The issue on clicking on Add More button, template gets added , but from dropdown I am not able to select or search for an option.
Follwing is my HTML:

```
<div id="form-repeater">
<div class="row">
  <select class="js-select2">
  </select>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
          id="add-more">Add More</button>
  </div>  
</div>




<div id="template" style='display: none;'>
  <div class="parent-div">
    <div class="row">
      <select class="js-select2">
      </select>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
              id="remove">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Following is my javascript:

```
$(".js-select2").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/651b234e-e668-4143-8c41-2e6a5bafcd27",
    delay: 250,
    processResults: processData
  },
  data: processData([{ "Id": "4", "Code": "JKL", "Description": "Juliet Kilo Laugh" }]).results,
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; } ,
  templateSelection: myCustomTemplate
});

function processData(data) {
  var mapdata = $.map(data, function (obj) {      
    obj.id = obj.Id;
    obj.text = '[' + obj.Code + '] ' + obj.Description;
    return obj;
  });
  return { results: mapdata }; 
}

function myCustomTemplate(item) {
     return '<strong>' + item.Code + '</strong> - ' + item.Description;
}

$("#add-more").click(function() {
    var content = $('#template').html();
  $('#form-repeater').append(content);
})

$(".remove").click(function(obj) {
    $(obj).closest('.parent-div').remove();
})
```

Comment: Dont forget to validate and upvote the answer if your problem is resolved

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.CourseAddButton', function() {
        var configParamsObj = {
                placeholder: 'Select an option...', // Place holder text to place in the select
                minimumResultsForSearch: 3 // Overrides default of 15 set above
                };

        var $thisTable = $(this).closest('table').find('tbody');
        var copyRow = $thisTable.find('tr:first');
        var hasSelect2 = $thisTable.find('.courseNameID').length;
        if (hasSelect2 !== 0) $thisTable.find(".courseNameID").select2('destroy');
        $thisTable.prepend(`<tr>${copyRow.html()}</tr>`);
        if (hasSelect2 !== 0) {
            $thisTable.find('.courseNameID').select2().next().next().remove();
            $thisTable.find('select.courseNameID').select2(configParamsObj);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When You execute `$(".js-select2").select2({...});`,  this selector initialize **all select2 linked to this selector**, so you initialize too your template.

so you have to copy the template and after you initialize the new select2 created.

so to avoid this problem, i have added `first()` to the selector

i have deleted the id of button remove and replaced by class.

Another error, when you create button dynamically, if you want to trap event, you have to use the delegation, so i have modifed the event click to destroy the select2 item.

```js
$("select.js-select2").first().select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/651b234e-e668-4143-8c41-2e6a5bafcd27",
    delay: 250,
    processResults: processData
  },
  data: processData([{
    "Id": "4",
    "Code": "JKL",
    "Description": "Juliet Kilo Laugh"
  }]).results,
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  escapeMarkup: function(m) {
    return m;
  },
  templateSelection: myCustomTemplate
});

function processData(data) {
  var mapdata = $.map(data, function(obj) {
    obj.id = obj.Id;
    obj.text = '[' + obj.Code + '] ' + obj.Description;
    return obj;
  });
  return {
    results: mapdata
  };
}

function myCustomTemplate(item) {
  return '<strong>' + item.Code + '</strong> - ' + item.Description;
}

$("#add-more").click(function() {
  var content = $('#template').html();
  $('#form-repeater').append(content);
  //console.log($("#form-repeater select.js-select2").length)
  $("#form-repeater select.js-select2").last().select2({
    ajax: {
      url: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/651b234e-e668-4143-8c41-2e6a5bafcd27",
      delay: 250,
      processResults: processData
    },
    data: processData([{
      "Id": "4",
      "Code": "JKL",
      "Description": "Juliet Kilo Laugh"
    }]).results,
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    escapeMarkup: function(m) {
      return m;
    },
    templateSelection: myCustomTemplate
  });
})

$("body").on("click", "button.remove", function() {
  $(this).closest('div.parent-div').remove();
})
```

```css
.js-select2 {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<div id="form-repeater">
  <div class="row">
    <select class="js-select2">
    </select>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-more">Add More</button>
  </div>
</div>




<div id="template" style='display: none;'>
  <div class="parent-div">
    <div class="row">
      <select class="js-select2">
      </select>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary remove">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```